# Gzip compressed and uncompressed web page size values

Tags: php, compression, gzip, html

I'm trying to build a feature to see the compressed level of a web page which already has Gzip installed on it.  [Similar to checkgzipcompression.com](http://checkgzipcompression.com).

Where it displays the values,
Uncompressed size: 5,174 bytes

Compressed size: 1,826 bytes

How can I get these values through php? I tried with filesize function:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$fileSize = filesize($url);
print_r($fileSize);
?>
```

But it displays an error as shown below:

```
Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://www.example.com in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\test.php on line 3

[replaced my domain with example.com]
```

How can I get it done?

Answer (score 0):

My solution for you question

```
$header = get_headers("http://wordpresskite.com", 1);
var_dump($header["Content-Length"]);
```